# vector of __mm128 won't push_back()

Tags: c++, visual-c++, sse

This simple SSE code:

```
#include <vector>
#include <emmintrin.h>

int main() {
    std::vector<__m128> blah;
    blah.push_back(__m128());
}
```

Crashes on MSVC 10 with a segfault at `0xffffffff`.

What could be going wrong ?

Comment: Alignment is gonna be the issue. The question is: how and howto fix

Comment: Adding __declspec(align(16)) on the datatype does not help. Also, `__m128` appears to be natively aligned: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ayeb3ayc.aspx

Comment: Variables of that type. Not objects placed into heap memory.

Comment: Ooh... I never tried that before. You're definitely running into alignment issues because the default allocator doesn't align to 16 bytes. You're gonna have to override the default allocator with your own.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A `std::vector` does not allocate specially aligned memory, which `__m128` needs to store it's data. You will have to either swap out the allocator, or replace it with an array of 4 floats and then perform an unaligned load or copy out to an aligned location every time you access the vector.