# Container of SSE types

Tags: c++, gcc

I am trying to store an SSE type in an stl container. I've tried this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
  typedef int v4sf __attribute__ (( vector_size(4*sizeof(float)) ));

  v4sf a; // compiles

  std::vector<v4sf> v1; // compiles, but nothing is actually allocated

//  std::vector<v4sf> v2(10); // compiler error: can’t convert between vector values of different size

  std::vector<v4sf> v(10, a); // Compiles, but segfaults

  return 0;
}
```

but as noted, allocating without providing an object to copy produces a compiler error, while allocating with providing an object compiles but segfaults. Can anyone explain why I can't store these SSE objects in an STL container like this (or better, provide a correct way to do it)?

Comment: `std::vector` doesn't guarantee alignment for SSE types.

Comment: [vector of __mm128 won't push_back()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11679741/vector-of-mm128-wont-push-back)

Comment: @Mystical, so how am I supposed to store them then? That thread doesn't actually show how to do it.

Comment: You have to override the default memory allocator with one that aligns properly. It's messy, but I'm not aware of any other way.

Comment: There is really no "built in" allocator to do this? It looks like a huge mess to write manually, and I don't really see any official looking "here use this for an Allocator for stl::vector and SSE" online anywhere - does one exist?

Comment: I dunno. I've never had a need put SSE objects into STL containers. I find that a simple aligned `malloc()` is sufficient for all the numerical stuff that warrants manual vectorization anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make it working, you have to implement a custom Allocator. To use it, it is the argument next to the type: 
std::vector< SSEType, CustomAlloc> container; 
Where CustomAlloc is the Allocator.
You have to use an alligned_malloc or memalign for getting memory inside of your Allocater, but this is the way to succeed here.

An example of such a (not so easy implementation) can be found here:
[Implementing Allocator example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4795/C-Standard-Allocator-An-Introduction-and-Implement)

I did already much with SSE and I observed, it is the most easy way to use an alligned malloc and use this for my calculations.